# recursive algorithm to sort children and parents based on value

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, sorting

### Task

Consider the following recursively-defined tree structure:

```
const tree = {
  val: 1,
  children: [
    {val: 2},
    {
      val: 3,
      children: [
        {
          val: 4,
          children: [
            {val: 5},
            {val: 6},
            {val: 7}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Here, each node in the tree is an object with a required "val" property that maps to a non-unique integer and an optional "children" property that, if present, maps to an array of child nodes. There will only be a single root node in the outermost object.

This challenge involves writing a function prioritizeNodes(tree, targetVal) which accepts a valid nested tree object conforming to the above definition. The function should sort all "children" arrays containing one or more nodes with node.val === targetVal to the front of the array. For the above tree, the output for a call to prioritizeNodes(tree, 7) would be:

```
const expected = {
  val: 1,
  children: [
    {
      val: 3,
      children: [
        {
          val: 4,
          children: [
            {val: 7},
            {val: 5},
            {val: 6}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {val: 2}
  ]
};
```

Each node in a tree with a value or child matching the target was moved to the front of its respective array.

Non-prioritized nodes should be kept in their original relative ordering with respect to one another, and prioritized nodes which were moved to the front of an array should also maintain order with respect to other priority nodes in the array. Your function may mutate the parameter tree in-place in addition to returning it if you wish.

### Examples

**Example 1**

```
const tree = {val: 1};
prioritizeNodes(tree, 1); // => {val: 1}
This is a trivial example.
```

**Example 2**

```
const tree = {
  val: 1,
  children: [
    {
      val: 1,
      children: [
        {val: 7}
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 3,
      children: [
        {val: 55}
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 2,
      children: [
        {val: 15}
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 7,
      children: [
        {val: 2}
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

A call to prioritizeNodes(tree, 2) on the above structure should return

```
const expected = {
  val: 1,
  children: [
    {
      val: 2, // <-- this moved up
      children: [
        {val: 15}
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 7, // <-- this moved up because its child has a val of 2
      children: [
        {val: 2}
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 1,
      children: [
        {val: 7}
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 3,
      children: [
        {val: 55}
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Note that the parent node with value 7 was considered to be prioritized because it contained a descendent with a value matching the target. All children of the root maintained relative ordering after moving high-priority nodes to the front.

**Example 3**

```
const tree = {
  val: 1,
  children: [
    {
      val: 2,
      children: [
        {
          val: 7,
          children: [
            {val: 2},
            {val: 18},
            {val: 12}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 4,
      children: [
        {val: 5},
        {
          val: 6,
          children: [
            {val: 12},
            {val: 11},
            {val: 10},
            {val: 9},
          ]
        },
        {val: 13}
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 3,
      children: [
        {val: 15}
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 17,
      children: [
        {val: 16},
        {
          val: 2,
          children: [
            {val: 14},
            {val: 11},
            {
              val: 18,
              children: [
                {val: 4},
                {val: 11},
                {val: 7}
              ]
            },
            {val: 27},
            {val: 18},
            {val: 29},
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

In this large example, prioritizeNodes(tree, 18) is expected to return

```
const expected = {
  val: 1,
  children: [
    {
      val: 2,
      children: [
        {
          val: 7,
          children: [
            {val: 18}, // <-- this moved up
            {val: 2},
            {val: 12}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 17, // <-- this moved up
      children: [
        {
          val: 2, // <-- this moved up
          children: [
            {
              val: 18, // <-- this moved up
              children: [
                {val: 4},
                {val: 11},
                {val: 7}
              ]
            },
            {val: 18}, // <-- this moved up
            {val: 14},
            {val: 11},
            {val: 27},
            {val: 29},
          ]
        },
        {val: 16}
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 4,
      children: [
        {val: 5},
        {
          val: 6,
          children: [
            {val: 12},
            {val: 11},
            {val: 10},
            {val: 9},
          ]
        },
        {val: 13}
      ]
    },
    {
      val: 3,
      children: [
        {val: 15}
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

### And My solution was:

````
class Node {
    val;
    children;

    constructor(data) {
        this.val = data.val || null
        if(data.children?.length > 0){
            this.children = []
            this.addChildren(data.children)
        }else if(this.children?.length <= 0){
            delete this.children
        }
    }
    addChildren(children) {
        if(children?.length > 0){
            for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                let newNode = new Node(children[i])
                this.children.push(newNode)
            }
        }
    }
}

function repeater(node, targetVal) {
    let parentFlag = false
    if(node.children?.length > 0){
        for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            if(repeater(node.children[i], targetVal)){
                node.children.unshift(...node.children.splice(i, 1))
                parentFlag = true
            }
        }
    }
    return node.val === targetVal || parentFlag;
}

const prioritizeNodes = (tree, targetVal) => {
    if(!tree.children){
        return tree
    }
    let newTree = new Node(tree)
    for (let i = 0; i < tree.children.length; i++) {
        repeater(newTree, targetVal)
    }
    return newTree
}
```
````

Comment: I don't know about others, but I don't want to read this wall of text. Please be concise. Hopefully, you can describe the problem and the solution in few paragraphs. Also, don't use code block for text: since it doesn't wrap the text and we have to use horizontal scroll. If the question is about coding and not about the algorithms, then you should ask it on [SO].

Comment: Where presenting contents you did not create yourself, please follow [How to reference material written by others](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If your post is long, introduce it to help decide quickly whether or not to invest more time, see [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). (Intentionally a different site.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a need for any interesting algorithm.  In its essence it is equivalent to the following: given an array $A$ of integers and an integer $x$, move all instances of $x$ to the front of $A$, keeping the rest in the same order.  Once you can solve that, you can apply it to each node of your tree.

To move all instances to the front, one approach is to collect a list of instances of $x$, collect a list of all the other instances, and then concatenate those lists.  Implemented correctly, you can do this in $O(n)$ time, where $n$ is the number of elements in the array.  Or, you can do it in $O(n)$ time and $O(1)$ space with a linear scan over the array and a clever bit of "swapping" of elements -- I'll let you work that out.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is almost correct, you just have to add an else statement to the repeater function to delete children when node.children are undefined

```
    if(repeater(node.children[i], targetVal)){
                    node.children.unshift(...node.children.splice(i, 1))
                    parentFlag = true
                }else{
 delete node.children
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution and still it didn't work ? can you provide further help ?

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck in the same challenge and with some help from stackoverflow community here's what worked for me :

shifting priority nodes into the children array will inverse the order of the priority nodes, which is not what is asked for.

avoiding mutation and creating two new children arrays in which the children are divided: one for the priority ones, and one for the other children. Then concatenate those two.
Let the recursive function return both the new children array and the flag.

```
   function prioritizeNodes(tree, targetVal) {
        function recur({val, children}) {
            if (!children) {
                return [{ val }, val === targetVal];
            }
            let categories = [[], []], 
                isPrio;
            for (let child of children) {
                [child, isPrio] = recur(child);
                categories[1-isPrio].push(child);
            }
            return [
                { val, children: categories.flat() },
                categories[0].length > 0 || val === targetVal
            ];
        }
        return recur(tree)[0];
    }
    
    // Example input
    let tree = {"val": 1,"children": [{"val": 2},{"val": 3,"children": [{"val": 4,"children": [{"val": 5},{"val": 6},{"val": 7}]}]}]}
    
    let result = prioritizeNodes(tree, 7);
    console.log(result);
```